# How to remove the undefined row() error in php

Tags: php

i get the code of knn algorithim from `http://jameshamilton.eu/old/datamining/k-nearest_neighbour.php?source`. i got error in undefined function row .kindly help me in removing this error.this the akgo of k -nearest algorithim

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="description" content="K Nearest Neighbour Algorithm - Data Mining" />
<meta name="keywords" content="k nearest neighbour, data mining, php, computer science, james hamilton" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="all" />
<meta name="revisit-after" content="1 days" />

<title>K Nearest Neighbour Algorithm - Data Mining</title>
<?php
include('admin_nb.php');
 // $date=$_GET['id'];echo"</br>";
  //$d=$_GET['id1'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
$db=mysql_select_db("vas1",$con);


?>

</head>

<body>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['source'])) {
    highlight_file(__FILE__);
}else{
if(!isset($_POST['k'])) $_POST['k'] = 3;
?>


    <form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    K:&nbsp;
    <select name="k">
        <?php foreach(range(1, 10) as $k) { ?>
            <option value="<?=$k?>" <?php if($k == $_POST['k']) { ?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>><?=$k?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>


    <table id="patients" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>

  <th>highest_dialled_call_type</th>
   <th>Age_less_than_30</th>
   <th>Age_greater_than_30</th>
   <th>Payment_on_time</th>
   <th>Pkg_activation</th>
   <th>Customer_profile</th>
   <th>Churn</th>
   <th>Proposed_pkg</th>
   <th>Distance</th>


        </tr>

    <?php

        /*
            --
            -- Table structure for table `datamining_diagnoses`
            --

            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datamining_diagnoses` (
              `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
              `sorethroat` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
              `fever` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
              `swollenglands` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
              `congestion` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
              `headache` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
              `diagnosis` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
              PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

            --
            -- Dumping data for table `datamining_diagnoses`
            --

            INSERT INTO `datamining_diagnoses` (`id`, `sorethroat`, `fever`, `swollenglands`, `congestion`, `headache`, `diagnosis`) VALUES
            (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'Strepthroat'),
            (2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 'Allergy'),
            (3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 'Cold'),
            (4, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 'Strepthroat'),
            (5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 'Cold'),
            (6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 'Allergy'),
            (7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 'Strepthroat'),
            (8, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 'Allergy'),
            (9, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 'Cold'),
            (10, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 'Cold');
        */

        /*
            function getRows takes an SQL query string (and a optional array key type - NUM or ASSOC)
            and returns and array containing all the rows of the query.

                define(ASSOC, 1);
                define(NUM, 2);

                function getRows($sql, $type=ASSOC) {
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    if($type == ASSOC) {
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            $ret[] = $row;
                    }else if($type == NUM) {
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
                            $ret[] = $row;
                    }else{
                        die("type should be NUM or ASSOC");
                    }
                    return $ret;
                }
        */


        $rows =getRows("SELECT * FROM knowledge_base;", NUM);


        $closest = -1;

        if(isset($_POST['diagnose'])) {
            $distance = array_fill(0, count($rows), 0);

            $instance = $_POST['instance'];

            for($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++) {

                for($j = 1; $j < 8; $j++) {
                    if($rows[$i][$j] != $instance[$j])
                        $distance[$i]++;
                }

            }


            asort($distance);

            $kclosest = array();

            foreach($distance as $key => $d)
                if(++$x <= $_POST[k]) {
                     $kclosest[$rows[$key][8]]++;
                     $newdistance[$key] = $d;
                }

            arsort($kclosest);
            $diagnosis = key($kclosest);

       }

        $a = 0;
        foreach($rows as $row) {

        ?>
            <tr <?php if(isset($newdistance[$a])) { ?> class="selected"<?php } ?>>
                 <td><?=$row[0] == international ? "international" : "onnet" : "offnet"; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row[1] == no ? "no" : "yes"; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row[2] == no ? "no" : "yes"; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row[3] == no ? "no" : "yes"; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row[4] == no ? "no" : "yes"; ?></td>
      <td><?=$row[5] == no ? "new" : "loyal"; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row[6] == no ? "no" : "yes"; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row[7]?></td>
                <td><?=$distance[$a++]?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php

        }
        ?>
        <tr>

                <td><input type="hidden" name="instance[]" value="11" />11</td>
                <td><select name="instance[]">
                        <option value="0"<?php if($_POST['instance'][0] == "international") echo "selected=\"selected\"";?>>international</option>
                        <option value="1"<?php if($_POST['instance'][0] == "onnet") echo "selected=\"selected\"";?>>onnet</option>
      <option value="2"<?php if($_POST['instance'][0] == "offnet") echo "selected=\"selected\"";?>>offnet</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><select name="instance[]">
                        <option value="0"<?php if($_POST['instance'][1] == "0") echo "selected=\"selected\"";?>>no</option>
                        <option value="1"<?php if($_POST['instance'][1] == "1") echo "selected=\"selected\"";?>>yes</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><select name="instance[]"&gt.
```

error come at line :`$rows =getRows("SELECT * FROM knowledge_base;", NUM);`
error is :  `Fatal error: Call to undefined function getRows() in C:\wamp\www\vas1\knn1.php on line 122`
kindly help in removing this error

Comment: The error says it all, getRows doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes it appears you have the function defintion of getRows commented out.

Answer (score 1):

You've commented out the definition of the getRows() function.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment your getRows() function so it looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="description" content="K Nearest Neighbour Algorithm - Data Mining" />
<meta name="keywords" content="k nearest neighbour, data mining, php, computer science, james hamilton" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="all" />
<meta name="revisit-after" content="1 days" />

<title>K Nearest Neighbour Algorithm - Data Mining</title>
<?php
include('admin_nb.php');
 // $date=$_GET['id'];echo"</br>";
  //$d=$_GET['id1'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
$db=mysql_select_db("vas1",$con);


?>

</head>

<body>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['source'])) {
    highlight_file(__FILE__);
}else{
if(!isset($_POST['k'])) $_POST['k'] = 3;
?>


    <form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    K:&nbsp;
    <select name="k">
        <?php foreach(range(1, 10) as $k) { ?>
            <option value="<?=$k?>" <?php if($k == $_POST['k']) { ?> selected="selected"<?php } ?>><?=$k?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>


    <table id="patients" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>

  <th>highest_dialled_call_type</th>
   <th>Age_less_than_30</th>
   <th>Age_greater_than_30</th>
   <th>Payment_on_time</th>
   <th>Pkg_activation</th>
   <th>Customer_profile</th>
   <th>Churn</th>
   <th>Proposed_pkg</th>
   <th>Distance</th>


        </tr>

    <?php
                define(ASSOC, 1);
                define(NUM, 2);

                function getRows($sql, $type=ASSOC) {
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    if($type == ASSOC) {
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            $ret[] = $row;
                    }else if($type == NUM) {
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
                            $ret[] = $row;
                    }else{
                        die("type should be NUM or ASSOC");
                    }
                    return $ret;
                }



        $rows =getRows("SELECT * FROM knowledge_base;", NUM);


        $closest = -1;

        if(isset($_POST['diagnose'])) {
            $distance = array_fill(0, count($rows), 0);

            $instance = $_POST['instance'];

            for($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++) {

                for($j = 1; $j < 8; $j++) {
                    if($rows[$i][$j] != $instance[$j])
                        $distance[$i]++;
                }

            }


            asort($distance);

            $kclosest = array();

            foreach($distance as $key => $d)
                if(++$x <= $_POST[k]) {
                     $kclosest[$rows[$key][8]]++;
                     $newdistance[$key] = $d;
                }

            arsort($kclosest);
            $diagnosis = key($kclosest);

       }

        $a = 0;
        foreach($rows as $row) {

        ?>
            <tr <?php if(isset($newdistance[$a])) { ?> class="selected"<?php } ?>>
                 <td><?=$row[0] == international ? "international" : "onnet" : "offnet"; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row[1] == no ? "no" : "yes"; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row[2] == no ? "no" : "yes"; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row[3] == no ? "no" : "yes"; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row[4] == no ? "no" : "yes"; ?></td>
      <td><?=$row[5] == no ? "new" : "loyal"; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row[6] == no ? "no" : "yes"; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row[7]?></td>
                <td><?=$distance[$a++]?></td>
            </tr>

        <?php

        }
        ?>
        <tr>

                <td><input type="hidden" name="instance[]" value="11" />11</td>
                <td><select name="instance[]">
                        <option value="0"<?php if($_POST['instance'][0] == "international") echo "selected=\"selected\"";?>>international</option>
                        <option value="1"<?php if($_POST['instance'][0] == "onnet") echo "selected=\"selected\"";?>>onnet</option>
      <option value="2"<?php if($_POST['instance'][0] == "offnet") echo "selected=\"selected\"";?>>offnet</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><select name="instance[]">
                        <option value="0"<?php if($_POST['instance'][1] == "0") echo "selected=\"selected\"";?>>no</option>
                        <option value="1"<?php if($_POST['instance'][1] == "1") echo "selected=\"selected\"";?>>yes</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><select name="instance[]"&gt.
```